# How to refresh CheckBoxes state after setting their IsChecked in code?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.Forms and can't solve this task now.
I have this fragment of XAML:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End">
        <Label x:Name="lbl_available_manufacturers" Text="Доступные производители" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" />
        <CheckBox x:Name="chk_available_manufacturers" CheckedChanged="chk_available_manufacturers_CheckedChanged" />
        <Button x:Name="btn_add_selected_manufacturers" Text="Добавить" Pressed="btn_add_selected_manufacturers_Pressed" />
    </StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="cv_available_manufacturers" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableManufacturers}"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    SelectionMode="None"
    HasUnevenRows="true"
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontSize="16" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

It looks like that:

[image]

I want to all children CheckBoxes to change state when parent CheckBox state changed.

I have this event handler:

```
    private void chk_available_manufacturers_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var itr = cv_available_manufacturers.TemplatedItems.GetEnumerator();

        while(itr.MoveNext())
        {
            PropertyInfo temp_pi = itr.Current.GetType().GetProperty("LogicalChildrenInternal", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); //OMG is this how I get children elements in Xamarin?!
            ReadOnlyCollection<Xamarin.Forms.Element> temp_list = (ReadOnlyCollection<Xamarin.Forms.Element>)temp_pi.GetValue(itr.Current);

            Grid temp_grid = (Grid)temp_list[0];
            CheckBox temp_chk = (CheckBox)temp_grid.Children[1];
            temp_chk.IsChecked = e.Value; //IsChecked changes it's state to a new one, but visually it does not change
        }
    }
```

What I need to do after setting `IsChecked` to all CheckBoxes, so they change their state on screen too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I need to do after setting IsChecked to all CheckBoxes, so they change their state on screen too?

Hi, try to set binding for the **IsChecked** property of the `CheckBox` for the item template. Please add a `bool` parameter to the model class and make it raise the `PropertyChanged` event to update the UI at runtime. Then detect the **IsChecked** event of the checkBox that is outside the listView to update the value of the parameter.

I tested a basic demo about the function, here is the sample code:

Page.xaml

```
<CheckBox CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"/>
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Content}"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
{
    TestPageViewModel viewModel;
    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new TestPageViewModel();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;

        foreach (var item in viewModel.DataCollection)
        {
            item.IsSelected = e.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Model class and ViewModel class:

```
public class TestPageModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string content;
    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            return content;
        }
        set
        {
            if (content != value)
            {
                content = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Content");
            }
        }
    }
    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class TestPageViewModel
{
    public TestPageViewModel()
    {
        DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<TestPageModel>();

        DataCollection.Add(new TestPageModel { Content = "item_1" });
        DataCollection.Add(new TestPageModel { Content = "item_2" });
        DataCollection.Add(new TestPageModel { Content = "item_3" });
        DataCollection.Add(new TestPageModel { Content = "item_4" });
        DataCollection.Add(new TestPageModel { Content = "item_5" });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TestPageModel> DataCollection { get; set; }
}
```